# JMSDiExtraBundle @Inject does not work in custom classes, but works in the controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Test class where I want to inject session service:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class TestDI
{

    /** @DI\Inject("session") */
    public $session;

}
```

Controller action that outputs the type of the test class:

```
... Controller {

/** @DI\Inject("session") */
private $session;

public function testAction()
{
    $test = new TestDI();
    echo gettype($this->session).'<br/>';
    echo gettype($test->session);
    return array();
}
```

gives me:

```
object
NULL
```

result. WHY @Inject does not work with my own class?

Comment: could you please verify the points in my answer? The property youre trying to inject is public ... that's good... but ... Is your bundle ( if containing the custom class ) in the list of configured bundle's ? ... otherwise ... Is your non-controller class inside one of the directories configured as `jms_di_extra.locations.directories` ?

Comment: I've checked you answer, and I've already tried to add `@Service` annotation - does not work. Property is always `public` - still does not work. Also I've tried to set `jms_di_extra.locations.directories` to  `"%kernel.root_dir%/../src"` - and still does not work

Comment: where is the class located that you're trying to use @Inject with (path/namespace) ? Did you maybe additionally provide an additional service definition in a xml / yml config file?

Comment: What additional service are you talking about? The TestDI class inside the same namespace as Controller that runs this class. (Acme\DemoBundle\Controller)

Comment: I am talking about a dublicate service definition without the injection configured. i.e. you add @service but already defined the class as a service in for example `Bundle\Resources\config\services.xml`

Comment: no, I just added created `@DI\Service` and didn't change my `services.yml` file

Comment: Did you try moving your custom controller out of the \Controller namespace? Important ... did you clear your cache after every annotation change? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36551/discussion-between-nifr-and-pleerock)

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your non-controller class as a service to make the DIExtra annotations work. Easiest way to achieve this is adding a class-level [@Service](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#service) annotation (`JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service`).

You have to make sure your non-controller class lives in a directory actually found by JMSDiExtraBundle. You can configure the bundles and directories that are being searched in the bundle's configuration:

```
jms_di_extra:
    locations:
        all_bundles: false
        bundles: [FooBundle, AcmeBlogBundle]
        directories: ["%kernel.root_dir%/../src"]
```

Further keep in mind:

> Note that you cannot use the @Inject annotation on private, or
>   protected properties.
>
> Likewise, the @InjectParams annotation does not work on protected, or private methods.

More information in the official documentation - [chapter non-controller classes](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage#non-controller-classes).

Comment: In what directory should i place my service classes? For example: /src/MyNS/SecurityExtensionBundle/services/MyService.php - that would be valid?